# Insert Modal data in table via Ajax PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to insert data from a table of my Modal into the table "parent" of my page, basically I have a modal, where I gave a select to bring the data that is not in the parent table and the user insert that data, what happens is that the requests are done correctly, however the data in the parent table comes "null", here my html page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="tablePrincipal">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Papéis funcionais do usuário
                    <button class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" name="Delete" value="Delete" id="deletar" ></button>
                    <button class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal"></button>
                </th><br>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <a style="cursor: pointer;"><td><input type='checkbox' id="checkTodos__" /><b>  Identificador</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td></a>
                <td><b>Nome</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            $SQL = "SELECT ADR.IDROLE, ADR.NMROLE, ADR.CDROLE FROM ADUSERROLE ADUR, ADROLE ADR WHERE ADUR.CDROLE = ADR.CDROLE AND ADUR.CDUSER = '".$cduser."'";

            $SQL.=" ORDER BY ADR.IDROLE, ADR.NMROLE";

            $cur = $conn->execute($SQL);

            if($cur){
                while(!$cur->EOF){
                    $linha = "<tbody><tr>";
                    $linha.= "<td> <input type='checkbox' />&nbsp;&nbsp;".$cur->fields['idrole']."</td>";
                    $linha.= "<td>".$cur->fields['nmrole']."</td>";
                    $linha.= "</tr></tbody>";
                    echo $linha;
                    $cur->MoveNext();

                    $cdrole = $cur->fields["cdrole"];
                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>  

<!-- Modal para exibição dos dados para adicionar na tabela pai -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Insira um novo registro</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <form id="formulario">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button class="fa fa-search" id="pesquisarDados" onclick="mostrarTabela();"></button>       
                    <label for="pesquisa">Pesquisar</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pesquisar" id="pesquisar" class="form-control" aria-describedby="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar">    
                    <table style="display: none;" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="mostraTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <a style="cursor: pointer;"><td><input type='checkbox' value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" /><b>  Identificador</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td></a>
                                <td><b>Nome</b><span class="gridSortAsc"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>    
                        <tbody id="mostraDadosTable">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>      
            </form>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inserirDado" onclick="insereDado();">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this form is inside my Modal. And here my JavaScript with Ajax, which makes the request for my PHP:

```
<script>
    //seleciona os checkbox
    $("#checkTodos__").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });

    $("#checkTodos__").click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $("#inputDado").change(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });

    $("#inputDado").click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    var checkTodos = $("#checkTodos");
    checkTodos.click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
        }
    });

    //limpa o campo de pesquisa do modal
    $('#Modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#formulario').each(function() {
            $('#pesquisar').val(''); 
        });
    });

    //mostra a tabela no modal quando clica no Pesquisar
    function mostrarTabela(){
        document.getElementById('mostraTable').style.display = '';
    }

    //quando não tiver algo digitado na pesquisa, irá trazer todos os registros
    function pesquisaTodosDados(){
        $('#mostraDadosTable').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
        $('#formulario').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',   
                url: 'actions.php',
                data: { 
                    selecionaDados: "true",
                    iduser: '1185621'
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //alert('sucesso');
                    for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                        //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
                        $('#mostraDadosTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'+data[i].idrole+'</td><td>'+data[i].nmrole+'</td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    //requisição assíncrona via Ajax e método Post para o arquivo getDados, e trás o que o usuário digitou na pesquisa
    function pesquisaDadosFiltrados(){
        $('#mostraDadosTable').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
        $('#formulario').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'getDados.php?pesquisar',
                data: {
                    pesquisar: $('#pesquisar').val()
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //Adicionando os registros filtrados na tabela
                    for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                        $('#mostraDadosTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="inputDado" name="inputDado" />&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data[i].idrole + '</td><td>' + data[i].nmrole + '</td></tr>', '');
                    };
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro na requisição');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    //dispara as funções para pesquisar todos os dados ou somente os dados filtrados, conforme requisição
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#pesquisarDados').click(function(){
            pesquisa = $('#pesquisar').val()
            pesquisarDados(pesquisa);
        });

        function pesquisarDados(pesquisa){
            if (pesquisa == "") {
                pesquisaTodosDados();
            } else {
                pesquisaDadosFiltrados();
            }
        }
    });

    //insere dados conforme requisição for disparada no botão salvar do modal
    function insereDado(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var arr = [];            
            $("input:checkbox[name=inputDado]:checked").each(function(){
                arr.push($(this).val());
                console.log('valor checkbox inputDado: ', arr);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'insertDado.php',
                data: {
                    insereDados : "true",
                    inputDado : arr
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('dado retornado: ', data);
                    console.log('valor checkbox inputDado no success: ', inputDado);
                    for(var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                        $('#tablePrincipal').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].idrole + '</td><td>' + data[i].nmrole + '</td></tr>');  
                    };
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro na requisição');
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

and finally, my page insertDado.php that does the INSERT in the table

```
<?php
define('NOSESSION', true);
require_once("../../global.php");
require_once("../specific/se_schulze.php");

$inputDado = $_POST['inputDado'];

function insereDados($inputDado){

global $conn;

$SQL = "INSERT INTO ADROLE (idrole, nmrole) 
            SELECT ADR.IDROLE, ADR.NMROLE FROM ADROLE ADR WHERE ADR.IDROLE = '" . $inputDado . "' AND ADR.NMROLE = '" . $inputDado . "'";

$cur = $conn->execute($SQL);

$vetor = "";
$registro = "";

if($cur){  
    $registro["idrole"] = $cur->fields["idrole"];
    $registro["nmrole"] = $cur->fields["nmrole"];
    $vetor[] = $registro;
}

echo json_encode($vetor);
```

}

```
insereDados($inputDado);
```

?>

some help? 
I've been trying to solve some time

Comment: in your ajax ftn when you populate the table with the results from data, are you certain the results are being populated? In your INSERT, you are assuming it will return a list of records. Try console.log in your JavaScript to see the results, or you can use alert.

Comment: this is my problem, when I fill in the results that came from the request, this data is being filled as nulls in the table, that is, console.log ('returned data:', data); comes null

Comment: If you want a list of records to populate your `$vector`, you might want to perform a select query.

Comment: What does the browser console window display for the output? if NULL or "" it's because you're returning an empty value.

Comment: also is the record being stored properly in your database? I don't see a `$conn->commit();`

Comment: exactly, this is the problem that I can not solve, would that select you speak in different querys or in the same query? for example, insert into (..., ...) select ..., or it would be separate

Comment: is being inserted in the database as null as well, because the value that arrives at the request is null

Comment: you have to access the variables that you are packing with your AJAX data, by using $_POST like so `$varA = $_POST['insereDados']; $varB = $_POST['inputDado'];` These are your inputs that you want to save to your database. Confirm that this works before continuing to fix your reply.

Comment: the variable I pass in my insert, I get it in the scope of my function in my file insertDado.php, thus $ inputDado = $ _POST ['inputData']; and in the date of the AJAX what I pass as insertData: "true" is the function that is in my file insertDado.php

Comment: I posted the complete code

Comment: Are your records saving correctly now?

Comment: by its logic, I made an insert with a select in the same query, but it is not populating my vector to return the data, they remain null :(

Comment: unsure of which method you're using to complete your execute, but here are some great examples and more tutorials on [PHP and MYSQL INSERTS](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)